# How to report all exceptions in JVM, be it own or third-party code?

Tags: java, gdb, exception

**Is there a way to log all exceptions happening within JVM?**

A system is built from a big number of smaller components provided by different groups. All of them are running within the same JVM (under Weblogic).

Error reporting policies are rather different in those groups, so sometimes we have cases of suppressed exceptions, which makes troubleshooting very hard. At the same time, I noticed that JDB is able to intercept any exception happening in the code, no matter where.

I'd like to use the same facility JDB uses in DEV/SIT/UAT environment to shorten issue resolution time. In PTE and PROD though the facility shall not only be turned off, but

- create no performance impact
- require no code change for turning it off.

Of course, I can have JDB connected to every instance of server running in DEV/SIT. It's feasible, I guess... but there are two main downside:

- it makes configuration more complex
- JDB stops when an exception has occured; need a script or something to let it continue

**So I wonder is there any method that does it, e.g. Runtime.traceExceptions(...)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no official Java API for this besides the debugging API which could be used also from inside the VM that is about to be 'debugged'.

An easier quick and dirty way to get notified of every exception that is created at runtime is to hack some tracing code directly into the constructor(s) of the Throwable class, compile it and put it into the `bootclasspath` before the rt.jar. This is of course nothing you should do in a release version but it can be very helpfull to analyse code that catches exceptions somewhere and doesn't report them properly.

*In response to the comments:*

Regarding the Debugger API: The last time I did something like this I used the [JVMDI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jvmdi-spec.html#JVMDI_EVENT_EXCEPTION) to build a native JNI/JVMDI dll and accessed it from inside the VM. It works and lets you do all sorts of wired things that Java normally doesn't offer but I would consider this even more of a hack than using a patched Throwable class. Besides that, the JVMDI has been deprecated and was replaced with JVM TI since Java 1.6. I don't know if and how you can do something like this with this new Debugger API as well.

Using a modified Throwable is fast, easy to get right, doesn't impose any performance degeneration by itself and also not even *really* hackish if you are in control over the execution environment. You could think of as some kind of AOP. ;) But I would still only use it to find otherwise hard to detect bugs and not in production code or only as a last resort. Something like this should surely not be considered as part of the design. The best long term approach would be to get all your development groups to agree on some common exception treatment.

Also [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can help a lot if you decide to do a code review to find all these spots where exceptions get caught and not reported.

Comment: I was considering bootstrap jar, as you said, but I'm afraid for my coworkers it would be too unholy :)

Comment: Apparently, Debugging API is only good when JVM has already started with remote debugging flag. I can start it with the flag too, but I'd like to keep the startup scripts unmodified, if possible. But it's a possible solution, for sure.

Comment: I decided to go with altered Throwable. It's gonna be some battles to get a permission to do that, but it's simplest and cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably un-jar the JDK, modify "Exception" to log your exception and then re-jar it.

It's a pretty reasonable solution and won't cause any problems--the JDK classes are, for the most part, just standard java classes.

You might be able to do it without modifying the JDK by manipulating the class path to read your version of "Exception" before reading the JDK's version--that way it wouldn't be as difficult to distribute.

Comment: Uh... crazy :) How about Javassist.

Answer (score 0):

GDB is designed for GCC built programs, If you are debugging a Java application I suggest you use the Java Debugger in your IDE.  It can be used to trap any exception thrown.

Note: some of the libraries throw exceptions during start up normally and imagine Weblogic has some of its own.

Comment: JDB. sorry, too many years in unix environment, GDB pops up in my head faster than JDB. Nope, IDE debugging is not the option -- I need to get a list of errors happen in the running systems, under some usage. It's not practical to have IDE/JDB session open all the time.

Comment: You could hack you own version of Throwable which writes itself to a log file (an any child as well). You would have to be careful to handle an failure in the logging very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project on Fedora - ABRT - automatic bug reporting tool.

It also reports uncaught JVM exceptions.

Right now (2013), an effort is started to make it also catch JBoss AS / EAP / WildFly exceptions.

Stay tuned to know when it comes: https://fedorahosted.org/abrt/milestone/Support_for_JAVA_exceptions